# NodeJS MySQL query gives 'undefined' rows

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm using mysql with nodeJS and creating a query. The rows I get for the query are 'undefined'. This has never happened to me before, and I'm stumped.

```
    // check if URL already exists in database
connection.query("SELECT * FROM shorturl WHERE urlsource='?'", [url], function(error, rows, fields){
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    if (rows.length == 0) {
        console.log(rows); //prints 'undefined'
        insertURL();
    } else {
        console.log("creating new entry");
        printURL();
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is really the `console.log(rows);` that prints `undefined`?  This does not make sense, because then the `rows.length` would throw a _cannot read property length of undefined_ error.

Comment: Oh, I modified the code later. Yes, I get the "cannot read property length of undefined" error first

Comment: And are you sure that `console.log(error);` does not log an error. You should wrap all of the code below `if (error) { console.log(error); }` in the `else` block of the `if  (error)`.

Comment: My guess is that you're getting an error because of the quotes around the placeholder in the query (`... WHERE urlsource = '?'`).

Comment: @robertklep Aren't those quotes necessary?

Comment: @t.niese I put it in the else block but I'm still getting the problem

Comment: If you use `?` then the `mysql` library will add quotes and does the the correct escaping if necessary. so writing `'?'` is indeed wrong, but it would either not show the correct result or will result in an error, but it does not exmplain your described behaviour.

Comment: I vote to remove the quotes as well. The library your using to send the query to MySQL will handle that.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this, a result from query connection NodeJS is array. Try to add rows[0] hope this will help.

```
if (rows[0].length == 0) {
    console.log(rows[0]);
    insertURL();
} else {
    console.log("creating new entry");
    printURL();
}
```